# remove data.frames in a list filled only with NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames and some of them are filled with NA, I would like to remove those data.frames with only NA in my list.

I am using these two commands:

```
list.df <- lapply(list.df, na.omit)
list.df <- list.df[sapply(list.df, function(x) dim(x)[1] >0 )]
```

Is there a way to do the same but in one line?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data so we can see how those commands are supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This keeps all `data.frame`s which have at least one `NA`-free row:

```
df.list[ sapply( df.list, function(x){ any( rowSums(is.na(x)) == 0 ) }) ]
```